# How to append the contents of a list at the end of the other list?

Tags: java, list, collections

How do I append the contents of one list at the end of another list?

Answer (score 54):

[`List.addAll()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection))

Answer (score 10):

listA.addAll(listB)

Answer (score 4):

```
List finalist = a + b
```

Example:

```
List a = [1,4]
List b = [2,3]
List c = a+b
```

Result:

```
c = [1, 4, 2, 3]
```